# To stop magento from creating its own base images of products from the ones uploaded

Tags: product-images, magento-1.9.2.1

I am using Magento 1.9 and find that when I upload an image for a product, Magento system picks it up and creates three versions of it as a small image, thumbnail and base image. I found that the base image dimensions, it is using are 600x600 in size.

So, I tried to upload same dimension size for it in view that it will pick up and use the same image as is but still it creates a new version of it which reduces its sharpness to some extent and thereby loss in clear image (especially if text area such as a brand name is present in it.)

How can I direct Magento to pick up the same image as a base image so that the effort put in prior to upload is not wasted just because Magento creates its own version. This is observed only with product images.